# Not able to Post on Facebook after getting approval of publish_actions from Facebook App Review team

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I have created app for sending post on user's wall on his behalf. I got publish_actions approval from Facebook team for this app. but still i am not able to send post. I am gettoing following error.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException: Insufficient permission for this operation.
```

[image]

There is also a problem when my app asking user for approval, its only showing public profile like following screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Have you added publish_actions to your code so it is asked for? Just because the permission is approved doesn't mean it will be asked for. And you should not ask for publish_actions for submission. You should ask for it when you need it

Comment: Nope. How to do that ?

Comment: It is described in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2#logindialog

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#login

You need to add a comma-separated list of your permissions for the `scope` parameter:

> `scope`. A comma separated list of Permissions to request from the person using your app.